# How to fix 'generator' object has no attribute 'to_csv' when exporting dataframe

Tags: python, oracle, pandas, sqlalchemy, export-to-csv

I am using Python to export data from an Oracle table into a Pandas DataFrame and then a CSV file.

But I am receiving this error:

```
AttributeError: 'generator' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
```

I can't find out where the problem with my code is:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

DATABASE = "MY database"
SCHEMA   = "MY USER"
PASSWORD = "MY PASS"
connstr  = "oracle://{}:{}@{}".format(SCHEMA, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
conn     = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connstr)
result=pd.read_sql('My QUERY' , con=conn, chunksize=10000)
result.to_csv("test",sep=',',chunksize=10000)
```

Comment: did you check the type of result it should not be generator as it seems from your question

Comment: You specified a `chunksize`, and the documentation tells you that that alters the return value type: *If specified, return **an iterator** where chunksize is the number of rows to include in each chunk.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are given an *iterator* of dataframes, not a single dataframe (a generator is a type of iterator), because you specified a `chunksize` value. See the [`pandas.read_sql()` documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_sql.html):

> **chunksize** : *int, default None*
>
> If specified, return an iterator where *chunksize* is the number of rows to include in each chunk.

You need to iterate over that iterator; the easiest way is to use a `for` loop. You then *don't want to use chunking again* when writing out your CSV file. You should instead open the output file in *append* mode, so that each chunk is added to the file as new rows:

```
chunks = pd.read_sql('My QUERY', con=conn, chunksize=10000)
for chunk in chunks:  # each chunk is a dataframe
    # append the data from each chunk to the same output file
    chunk.to_csv("test.csv", sep=",", mode="a")
```

This is not really an efficient way to produce a CSV file from your table however! You'll get your CSV file much more efficiently if you used the Oracle SQL*Plus command-line tool, see Oracle’s own blog post, [Fast Generation of CSV and JSON from Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database).

Even just streaming the SQLAlchemy query directly to a `csv.writer()` object would be better:

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

DATABASE  = "MY database"
SCHEMA    = "MY USER"
PASSWORD  = "MY PASS"
BATCHSIZE = 10000
connstr   = "oracle://{}:{}@{}".format(SCHEMA, PASSWORD, DATABASE)
engine   = sqlalchemy.create_engine(connstr, arraysize=BATCHSIZE)
conn     = engine.connect()
with open("test.csv", "w") as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    results = conn.execute('My QUERY')
    writer.writerows(results)
```

The `cx_Oracle` library then streams results in batches from the database to Python for you, and `writer.writerows()` writes these to your CSV file. The batch size is controlled by the `arraysize` parameter, which instructs the cx_Oracle library to load that many rows per round-trip between server and client. You probably want to set that in your Panda's code too if you *must* use DataFrames.

You don't need SQLAlchemy either, really; you can just use cx_Oracle directly here, and set the [`cursor.arraysize` parameter](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/cursor.html#Cursor.arraysize):

```
import cx_Oracle
import csv

DATABASE  = "MY database"
SCHEMA    = "MY USER"
PASSWORD  = "MY PASS"
BATCHSIZE = 10000

conn      = cx_Oracle.connect(user=SCHEMA, password=PASSWORD, dsn=DATABASE)
cursor    = connection.cursor()
cursor.arraysize = BATCHSIZE

with open("test.csv", "w") as outputfile:
    writer = csv.writer(outputfile)
    results = cursor.execute('My QUERY')
    writer.writerows(results)
```

Comment: It's probably more efficient to use SQL*Plus instead of SQL Developer to export CSV, see [Fast Generation of CSV and JSON from Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/fast-generation-of-csv-and-json-from-oracle-database)

Comment: @ChristopherJones probably, I just didn’t know that existed :-) I see you can tune the arraysize and row prefetch params too! It’s been about half a decade since I last touched Oracle tools..

Comment: @MartijnPieters , Thanks a lot for your awesome answer. it worked for me. and the suggestion was great. I always have to export millions of records from oracle and I really needed an efficient way.